# Bounded Solution of a Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a linear differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = a(x)y + b(x)$ where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are continuous functions on $x \geq 0$. If $a(x) \leq -m < 0$ and $b(x)$ is bounded, then any solution of the differential equation is bounded.

We know that the solution to the above differential equation is given by
$$y(x) = \exp(A(x)) \left[ \int\exp(-A(x))b(x)dx + C \right],$$

where $A(x) = \int a(x) dx$ and $C$ is a constant.

We know that $a(x) \leq -m$, and so, $A(x) \leq \int (-m)dx = -mx$. Thus, $\exp(A(x)) \leq \exp(-mx)$. But $\exp(-A(x)) \geq \exp(mx)$.

Also since $b(x)$ is bounded, we have $|b(x)| \leq M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thus,

\begin{align*}
|y(x)| &= \left|\exp(A(x) \left[ \int\exp(-A(x))b(x)dx + C \right] \right| \\
&\leq |\exp(A(x)| \left[\int |\exp (-A(x)| |b(x)| dx + |C| \right].
\end{align*}

From here, I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The point is to move the $e^{A(x)}$ factor inside. $$y(x)=\int_0^x e^{A(x)-A(x’)}b(x’)dx’+Ce^{A(x)}.$$ Note that $$A(x’)-A(x)=\int_x^{x’}a(z)dz\leq-m(x-x’)\leq0$$ if $x’\leq x$. From here you can see how to finish.

Comment: Thank you very much.